# Do Azure Container Instances share a HTTP connection pool?

Tags: azure, http, azure-container-instances

I understand that ACI's (Azure Container Instances) share resources in a Container Group. A fair amount is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups#how-a-container-group-works).

However, does anyone know if Container Instances share a HTTP connection pool in their respective Container Group?

I ask, because I am running many concurrent HTTP requests for a process (multiple copies of the same process running) and I am wondering if it is more beneficial to split out the work into separate Container Groups or Instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if Container Instances share a HTTP connection pool
>   in their respective Container Group?

Generally, the HTTP connection pool is defined on the host. One host would share the same HTTP connection pool. And you can see the description below in the document that you provided:

> A container group is a collection of containers that get scheduled on
>   the same host machine.

So according to this, I think the containers in the same container group cloud share the same HTTP connection pool.

Comment: Yes, that has been my thoughts as well. 

I think you are right and will likely mark this as the answer if no one else has any further input soon.

Comment: @DDN-Shep What about now? Still waiting for more answers?